# Isn't my W-2 federal income tax withheld too low?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, withholding, form-w-2

My wife and I file our income taxes as "Married Filing Jointly". There seems to be a drastic difference on our W-2 forms. She has been at her job for 15 years and her W-2 has changed very gradually and without any confusion (i.e. her wages and withholdings have changed predictably), whereas this is my first year full time at my current position. So I am using her W-2 as the "standard" of correctness.

We both claimed **0 allowances**. As far as I know, neither of us withheld any additional amount from our paychecks. However, here is the issue. My W-2 Box-1 "Wages, tips, and other compensation" for 2019 was roughly **1.25 times greater** than hers. However, my Box 2 "Federal income tax withheld" was only **1.07 times greater** than hers (but my "Medicare tax withheld" and "social security tax withheld" were both closer (as 1.19) to our Box-1 ratio (which as stated above was 1.25)).

She did additionally have pension and health benefits deducted from each paycheck. *Even then, why wasn't my amount of Federal Withholdings much higher than it was? Shouldn't my withholdings have been higher, bringing us closer to the 1.25 Box-1 ratio on our W-2 forms?* (instead of the observed value of 1.07)

Comment: Does your wife receive a greater percent of target income as a quarterly or annual bonus?  Bonus payout withholding is calculated conservatively.

Comment: @user662852 no she doesn't have a bonus

Comment: @TTT I have 401K payroll deductions - but this is pre-tax so doesn't matter right?

Answer (score 2):

My W-2 has an Earnings Summary which shows how Box 1 is computed.  Apparently yours doesn't.

On my W-2, Box 1 is computed such:

1. Starts with Gross Pay.  Look at your final 2019 pay stub.
2. Adds Box 12 *Type C* (Group Term Life Insurance) money.
3. Subtracts Box 12 *Type D* (401k) money.
4. Subtracts "Other Cafe 125" money.  Look on your final pay stub for the YTD values of benefits "Excluded from federal taxable wages" and add them up; that's your "Other Cafe 125" money.

You and your wife might have other benefits, but we promise you: what's on your final pay stub matches what's on your W-2, unless your payroll provider really cocked something up (and that's pretty unlikely).

Comment: yes it matches but the withholdings seem to be too low for our tax bracket. However I checked this resource - https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15t.pdf - and it seems like the amount is correct. I will need to add additional withholdings via w-4